# Magento2 : Create Custom Condition Field like Catalog Price Rule with my Own values

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, admin-panel, catalog-price-rules

In Magento 2 Custom form i would like to add condition field like Catalog Price Rule with my custom values. Please find below screen shot.

Screen shot:

[image]

please suggest me how to get.

Answer (score 0):

> Follow the Below link is a full Example.

[**Click Here For Part 1**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344611/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 2**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 3**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344613/82670)

**Replace class in** **CustomCondition.php** **at** **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model**

**From**

```
....
\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
....
```

**To**

```
....
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
....
```

**[Check condition with products in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344617/82670)**

Answer (score -2):

[Click here](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/)  to get detail explanation of how to create custom module with condition tab in magento 2. Credit goes to @MageWorx