# Magento 2 How to put a rule condition into the custom admin form using the ui component

Tags: magento2, rules

Magento 2 custom extension how to put a rule condition into the custom admin form using the ui component with data base interaction.

please refer the following rule condition image

[image]

Comment: have you got any solution? i want to also implement same functionality using UI component.

Comment: No i am not get

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: No, I don't get any solution

Answer (score 1):

[Click Here For Part 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

**After adding above files you can see condition field into your form**

In above section we create admin grid and form. In **custom_condition_form.xml** form file at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/view/adminhtml/ui_component** uncomment below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_form.custom_condition_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_form.custom_condition_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">general_information</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Back</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Reset</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Save</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    ............................................................................................................
```

**Step-19:** Create **Generic.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;

class Generic
{
    protected $context;
    protected $pageRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

**Step-20:** Create **Back.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Back extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10,
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/');
    }
}
```

**Step-21:** Create **Reset.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Reset implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Reset'),
            'class' => 'reset',
            'on_click' => 'location.reload();',
            'sort_order' => 30,
        ];
    }
}
```

**Step-22:** Create **Delete.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Delete extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [];
        $rule_id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
        if ($rule_id) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'class' => 'delete',
                'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                    'Are you sure you want to delete this?'
                ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
                'sort_order' => 20,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        $rule_id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['rule_id' => $rule_id]);
    }
}
```

**Step-23:** Create **Save.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Container;

class Save extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'custom_condition_form.custom_condition_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    false,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'class_name' => Container::SPLIT_BUTTON,
            'options' => $this->getOptions(),
        ];
    }

    protected function getOptions()
    {
        $options[] = [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_new',
            'label' => __('Save & New'),
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'custom_condition_form.custom_condition_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    true,
                                    [
                                        'back' => 'add',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_close',
            'label' => __('Save & Close'),
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'custom_condition_form.custom_condition_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    true,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

**After We Creating controller action file form perform CRUD operation.**

**Step-24:** Create **Rule.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

abstract class Rule extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $coreRegistry = null;
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $dateFilter;
    protected $ruleFactory;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter,
        \VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomConditionFactory $ruleFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->dateFilter = $dateFilter;
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected function _initRule()
    {
        $rule = $this->ruleFactory->create();
        $this->coreRegistry->register(
            'current_rule',
            $rule
        );
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if (!$id && $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id')) {
            $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
        }

        if ($id) {
            $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_rule')->load($id);
        }
    }

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Step-25:** Create **NewActionHtml.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class NewActionHtml extends \VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Rule
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $typeArr = explode('|', str_replace('-', '/', $this->getRequest()->getParam('type')));
        $type = $typeArr[0];

        $model = $this->_objectManager->create(
            $type
        )->setId(
            $id
        )->setType(
            $type
        )->setRule(
            $this->ruleFactory->create()
        )->setPrefix(
            'actions'
        );
        if (!empty($typeArr[1])) {
            $model->setAttribute($typeArr[1]);
        }

        if ($model instanceof \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition) {
            $model->setJsFormObject("custom_condition_form");
            $model->setFormName("custom_condition_form");
            $html = $model->asHtmlRecursive();
        } else {
            $html = '';
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);
    }
}
```

**Step-26:** Create **Delete.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Delete extends Action
{
    protected $customConditionModel;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomConditionFactory $customConditionModel
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customConditionModel = $customConditionModel;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $model = $this->customConditionModel->create();
                $model->load($id);
                $model->delete();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The rule is deleted successfully.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['rule_id' => $id]);
            }
        }
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('The rule does not exist'));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

**Step-27:** Create **Save.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomConditionFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $ruledatamodel;
    protected $dataPersistor;
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        CustomConditionFactory $ruledatamodel
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->ruledatamodel = $ruledatamodel;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
            $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
        }
        if (isset($data['rule'])) {
            unset($data['rule']);
        }
        try {
            $model = $this->ruledatamodel->create();
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This rule is no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('addconditionfiled/index/index');
            }
            $model->loadPost($data);
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Rule has been successfully saved.'));
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back') == 'add') {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('addconditionfiled/index/add');
                } else {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath(
                        'addconditionfiled/index/edit',
                        [
                            'rule_id' => $model->getId(),
                        ]
                    );
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('addconditionfiled/index/add');
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('addconditionfiled/index/index');
    }
}
```

**Step-28:** Create **Edit.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Edit Rule'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Step-29:** Create **addconditionfiled_index_edit.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/view/adminhtml/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="custom_condition_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

***Now your Admin from and grid are ready for CRUD Operation.***

**[Check condition with products in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344617/82670)**

Comment: It's hardcoded a lot, but in general I used it like example.
**VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\DataProvider** this file is not provided.


For people who knows what to do it will be useful. Thanks for it. 


I have added all code, that you wrote to the separate github repo, with some small changes that you missed. 
Hope it will be helpful for someone: https://github.com/bbakalov/AddConditionFiled_stackoverflow

Comment: This working, but cannot undertand why I cannot select categories from rules

Answer (score 0):

For adding condition element try to add next:

1) ui_component/your_name.xml :

```
<container name="display_container">
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">YourName\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Rule\Edit\Tab\ProductConditions</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
```

2) How to create condition block - look at this Magento file:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Block/Adminhtml/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Conditions.php
```

I hope this information will help you to add custom conditions on your form.

Comment: Hello @amasty please provide the full tutorial without the field we can not initialize into the ui component

Comment: any answers from other developers ?

Answer (score 0):

Too late but it may help someone.In ui_component form

> ui_component_form

```
<fieldset name="conditions">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Conditions</label>
        </settings>
        <container name="conditions_apply_to" sortOrder="10">
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <block name="conditions_apply_to" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Conditions" />
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
</fieldset>
```

> Conditions.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements
    \Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_nameInLayout = 'conditions_apply_to';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory|null $ruleFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = [],
        \Vendor\Module\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory = null
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('registry_name');
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of conditions tab to supplied form.
     *
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $model
     * @param string $fieldsetId
     * @param string $formName
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset', $formName = 'your_ui_component_form_name')
    {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->ruleFactory->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        // $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'Admin_routes/contoller_name/newConditionHtml/form/' . $fieldsetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Vendor_Module::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $newChildUrl
        )->setFieldSetId(
            $fieldsetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            [
                'name'           => 'conditions',
                'label'          => __('Conditions'),
                'title'          => __('Conditions'),
                'required'       => true,
                'data-form-part' => $formName
            ]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of form name to condition and its conditions.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions
     * @param string $formName
     * @return void
     */
    private function setConditionFormName(\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions, $formName)
    {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        if ($conditions->getConditions() && is_array($conditions->getConditions())) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> newConditionHtml.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\controller_name;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition;

class NewConditionHtml extends \Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $formName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_namespace');
        $typeArr = explode('|', str_replace('-', '/', $this->getRequest()->getParam('type')));
        $type = $typeArr[0];

        $model = $this->_objectManager->create($type)
            ->setId($id)
            ->setType($type)
            ->setRule($this->_objectManager->create(\Vendor\Module\Model\Rule::class))
            ->setPrefix('conditions');

        if (!empty($typeArr[1])) {
            $model->setAttribute($typeArr[1]);
        }

        if ($model instanceof AbstractCondition) {
            $model->setJsFormObject($this->getRequest()->getParam('form'));
            $model->setFormName($formName);
            $html = $model->asHtmlRecursive();
        } else {
            $html = '';
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);
    }
}
```

> Rule.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Rule extends \Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel
{
    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;
    
    const CACHE_TAG = 'cache_tag';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'page_tag';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'event_prefix';

    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory */
    /**
    * CMS page cache tag.
    */
    const TYPE_ID = 'id';
    const NAME = 'name';

    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';

    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory */
    protected $condCombineFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory */
    protected $condProdCombineF;

    /**
     * Store already validated addresses and validation results
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Initialize resource model.
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');
    }
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
    public function getAvailableStatuses()
    {
        return [self::STATUS_ENABLED => __('Enabled'), self::STATUS_DISABLED => __('Disabled')];
    }
    /**
     * Get rule condition combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
     */
    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get rule condition product combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine
     */
    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condProdCombineF->create();
    }

    /**
     * Check cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Set validation result for specific address to results cache
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @param bool $validationResult
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    /**
     * Return id for address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }
    

}
```

> fieldset.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**@var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $block */
?>
<?php $_element = $block->getElement(); ?>
<?php $_jsObjectName = $block->getFieldSetId() != null ? $block->getFieldSetId() : $_element->getHtmlId(); ?>
<script>require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
        $('div[data-index="conditions"]').click(function(){
        $('select[name="rule[conditions][1][new_child]"] optgroup[label="Cart Attribute"] option:nth-child(5)').css('display','none');
}); 
});</script>
<div class="rule-tree">
    <fieldset id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_jsObjectName ?>" <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_element->serialize(['class']) ?> class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_element->getLegend() ?></span></legend>
        <br>
    <?php if ($_element->getComment()): ?>
        <div class="messages">
            <div class="message message-notice"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_element->getComment()) ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="rule-tree-wrapper">
        <?= $_element->getChildrenHtml() ?>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script>
require([
    "Magento_Rule/rules",
    "prototype"
], function(VarienRulesForm){

window.<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_jsObjectName ?> = new VarienRulesForm('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_jsObjectName ?>', '<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getNewChildUrl() ?>');
<?php if ($_element->getReadonly()): ?>
    <?= $_element->getHtmlId() ?>.setReadonly(true);
<?php endif; ?>
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Follow Below Steps:

**Step-1:** Create **registration.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_AddConditionFiled',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step-2:** Create **module.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_Checkout"></module>
           <module name="Magento_Catalog"></module>
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-3:** Create **InstallSchema.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Setup**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('VendoreName_custom_condition')) {
            $tableName = $installer->getTable('VendoreName_custom_condition');
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    10,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true,
                    ],
                    'Rule ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_status',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Rule Status'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_name',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Rule Name'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'conditions_serialized',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    '2M',
                    [],
                    'Conditions Serialized'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'actions_serialized',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    '2M',
                    [],
                    'Actions Serialized'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'create_date',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    [
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT,
                    ],
                    'Create Date Time'
                )
                ->setComment('VendoreName Demo For Condition Field')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Here conditions_serialized and actions_serialized are used to store condition field value. So you must be add into you table. After creating table we add resource model and collection. Our Model name is CustomCondition.

**Step-4:** Create **CustomCondition.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition as CustomConditionResourceModel;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;

class CustomCondition extends AbstractModel
{
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'VendoreName_addconditionfiled';
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    protected $condCombineFactory;
    protected $condProdCombineF;
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];
    protected $_selectProductIds;
    protected $_displayProductIds;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init(CustomConditionResourceModel::class);
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }

    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }

    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }

    public function getConditionsFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_conditions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getActionFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_actions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getMatchProductIds()
    {
        $productCollection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection'
        );
        $productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory'
        );
        $this->_selectProductIds = [];
        $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);
        $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator'
        )->walk(
            $productCollection->getSelect(),
            [[$this, 'callbackValidateProductCondition']],
            [
                'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
                'product' => $productFactory->create(),
            ]
        );
        return $this->_selectProductIds;
    }

    public function callbackValidateProductCondition($args)
    {
        $product = clone $args['product'];
        $product->setData($args['row']);
        $websites = $this->_getWebsitesMap();
        foreach ($websites as $websiteId => $defaultStoreId) {
            $product->setStoreId($defaultStoreId);
            if ($this->getConditions()->validate($product)) {
                $this->_selectProductIds[] = $product->getId();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getWebsitesMap()
    {
        $map = [];
        $websites = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'
        )->getWebsites();
        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            if ($website->getDefaultStore() === null) {
                continue;
            }
            $map[$website->getId()] = $website->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        }
        return $map;
    }
}
```

**Step-5:** Create **CustomCondition.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomCondition extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('VendoreName_custom_condition', 'rule_id');
    }
}
```

**Step-6:** Create **Collection.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel/CustomCondition**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomCondition as CustomConditionModel;
use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition as CustomConditionResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomConditionModel::class,
            CustomConditionResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

**Step-7:** Create **Collection.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel/CustomCondition/Grid**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Collection as CustomConditionCollection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document as CustomConditionModel;

class Collection extends CustomConditionCollection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $aggregations;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = CustomConditionModel::class,
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step-8:** Create **di.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_condition_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>

    </type>
</config>
```

**Step-9:** Create **routes.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="addconditionfiled" frontName="addconditionfiled">
            <module name="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step-10:** Create **Index.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Add Rules'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Step-11:** Create **menu.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
   <menu>
        <add id="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled"
             title="VendoreName - Add Condition Field"
             translate="title"
             module="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled"
             sortOrder="10"
             parent="Magento_Backend::marketing"
             resource="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled" />

        <add id="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::menu"
             title="Add Rules"
             module="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled"
             sortOrder="100"
             parent="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled"
             action="addconditionfiled/index/index"
             resource="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::menu"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

[**Click Here For Part 2**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here For Part 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344611/82670)

**Step-12:** Create **addconditionfiled_index_index.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/view/adminhtml/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="custom_condition_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step-13:** Create **custom_condition_listing.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Rule</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/add</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="custom_condition_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="custom_condition_columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_listing.custom_condition_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="rule_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rule Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="rule_status">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Enable</item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">45</item>
              <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </item>
              <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Disable</item>
              <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            </item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
              <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
              <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="rule_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rule Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AddConditionFiledActions">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Step-14:** Create **AddConditionFiledActions.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Ui/Component/Listing/Column**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class AddConditionFiledActions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $urlBuilder;

    const URL_DELETE_PATH = 'addconditionfiled/index/delete';
    const URL_VIEW_PATH = 'addconditionfiled/index/edit';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item['rule_id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'view' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_VIEW_PATH,
                                [
                                    'rule_id' => $item['rule_id'],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit'),
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_DELETE_PATH,
                                [
                                    "rule_id" => $item['rule_id'],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                            'confirm' => [
                                'title' => __('Delete'),
                                'message' => __('Are you sure you want to delete this rule ?'),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Step-15:** Create **Add.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Add extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Add New Rule'));
        return $resultPage;
    }

}
```

**Step-16:** Create **addconditionfiled_index_add.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/view/adminhtml/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="custom_condition_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step-17:** Create **custom_condition_form.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/view/adminhtml/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_form.custom_condition_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_form.custom_condition_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">general_information</item>
        <!-- <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Back</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Reset</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Save</item>
        </item> -->
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="custom_condition_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_condition_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
              </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="rule_data">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rule Information</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="rule_status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="boolean" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">rule_status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="rule_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">25</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rule Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">rule_name</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">rule_name</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="condition_data">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Condition</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="conditions_serialized">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\ConditionField\Condition</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Step-18:** Create **Condition.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/ConditionField**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\ConditionField;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Condition extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    protected $_conditions;

    protected $_nameInLayout = 'conditions';

    private $ruleFactory;

    private $CustomConditionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        \VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomConditionFactory $CustomConditionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        $this->CustomConditionFactory = $CustomConditionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    private function getRuleFactory()
    {
        if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
            $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomConditionFactory');
        }
        return $this->ruleFactory;
    }

    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_rule');
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    protected function addTabToForm(
        $model,
        $fieldsetId = 'conditions_serialized_field',
        $formName = 'custom_condition_form'
    ) {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
            $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'catalog_rule/promo_catalog/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $newChildUrl
        )->setFieldSetId(
            $conditionsFieldSetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                ),
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'conditions',
                'label' => __('Conditions'),
                'title' => __('Conditions'),
                'required' => true,
                'data-form-part' => $formName,
            ]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
        return $form;
    }

    private function setConditionFormName(\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions, $formName)
    {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        if ($conditions->getConditions() && is_array($conditions->getConditions())) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Click Here For Part 3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344613/82670)