# Magento2 : Custom Sales Rule condition and validation

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.6, custom-validation

I am using [this](https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-custom-sales-rule-condition/) article to create a custom condition in the cart rule where I want to add the stock qty including other product attributes in the rule condition.

For example
if product_attribute1 = Adidas and product_qty >= 100 apply the rule on that product.

I can add conditions successfully, but when I try to validate the rule with product qty. I am facing some issues.

When I debug the code and find that there is the wrong class attached in `$model`

```
echo get_class($model);
```

result: `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address`

I have changed Customer `(Magently\CustomerRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Customer)` class to Product `(Magently\CustomerRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product)` class, but still it showing `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` in validate function.

I need the `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` class, as I review the core functionality so that I can get the product qty and validate the product qty before applying the rule in the cart.

Please let me know where the address class is defined SO I can change it or is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Follow the Below link is a full Example.

[**Click Here For Part 1**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344611/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 2**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 3**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344613/82670)

**For Sales Rule Replace class in** **CustomCondition.php** **at** **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model**

**From**

```
....
\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
....
```

**To**

```
....
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
....
```